# How to use a fontello image fonts ttf file in android studio?

Tags: android, fontello

I am trying to reduce the app size using fontello image fonts but not sure of ways to do this.
I am not able to find any good reference to implement the same in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Fontello is used for web pages as they have mentioned in the license. So there is not any good way to add it to a native Android application. [Link](https://github.com/fontello/fontello)
[image]